# SIM IccId - logged anywhere?

Tags: huawei, sim-card

Is there anywhere I can find historical traces of the IccId? By that I mean, something to indicate the identity of the sim card at some point back in time.

Ideally, this would be as far back as possible. Any "recorded" instance of IccId would be of relevance - system logs, attributes in SMS or call log - anything, really.

I doubt the background is relevant, but if anyone is curious:

In the peculiar case of my carrier disagreeing with what my SIM card's IccId is (and as a consequence, I assume, which physical sim card I actually possess) I've experienced the following:

- I read the IccId off of the physical card, let's call this number 123.
- When I ask my carrier for the PUK code, the response is an IccId (let's call it 456) and a PUK. 456 is different from 123 (very different - it's not a typo or anything) and the PUK (naturally) doesn't work on my sim.
- When I say that IccId 456 is not the number that appears on my sim, seemingly nobody is able to figure out why they're showing an IccId for me that isn't the sim that I physically possess.
- I've spoken to 3rd level techs and they say that IccId 123 was produced a year ago, but registered to the network only a week ago (despite having been in my phone for well over a year)... but is not and has never been in "actual use".
- They also say that they see activity from IccId 456 consistent with the activity I've relayed to them.

I've used my phone without significant issue (the only issue being that I was unable to get a form of mobile banking authorization based on a Sim Toolkit-equivalent, and I'm now guessing that this must be significantly related to the IccId disagreement) for the past year, so any notion that my sim card hasn't been in use, or registered prior to a week ago, is empirically untrue.

The phone is a Huawei Honor 8 (FRD-L09, bought in Europe if that matters). It is not rooted so I would prefer non-root approaches (though root approaches are still welcome).